# Why can't I import textgenrnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to install and run textgenrnn 2 in python 3.9.4. As far as I can tell the installation went fine, but when I try

```
from textgenrnn import textgenrnn
```

I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'multi_gpu_model' from 'tensorflow.keras.utils'
```

I've tried different versions of textgenrnn, python, keras, and other packages, but I can't find a combinations that works.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your import statements?

Comment: There aren't any. I'm just running that single line of code.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using python 3.7.9, tensorflow 2.3.2, and keras 2.3.0 following the advice here https://github.com/minimaxir/textgenrnn/issues/222